# ping server 2008 and client windows 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008

server IP is 192.168.49.252 and client IP is 192.168.49.128

the client can ping the server but server cant ping the client, although server run the SW on the client but slowly slowly. it ping the other client of IP 192.168.49.208. how can i resolve.
thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: How does this relate to your client/server application problem? (Clue: it doesn't). How much time have you spent troubleshooting your ping problem rather than troubleshooting the real problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ping is part of the ICMP protocoll - in fact it is called "ICMP Echo Request". This can be blocked by the firewall. Look into the Windows Firewall Rules on the client that can not be pinged. Look for an incoming rule named "File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request –ICMPv4-In)" and, if disabled, enable it.

Answer (score 0):

possibly firewall rules /settings for ICMPv4 ? 
Check  Windows Firewall --> Advanced settings --> Inbound rules 
in Protocol and ports: Protocol: ICMPv4 check the box for "echo request" is checked.